# Unexpected Symbol in As Formula, Can't Find

Tags: r, string, text, syntax-error, formula

I've been using `as.formula` for setting up a glm, and I can't figure out where the unexpected symbol is. Part of the problem is that the character vector I'm converting is so long. It's about 700 words with `+` inserted in between in order to turn it into a formula. The error presents as follows:

```
Error in parse(text = x, keep.source = FALSE) : 
   <text>:2:10080: unexpected symbol
```

with the following snippet of the text:

```
2: c_1_E + Campaign_Search_Payroll_Generic_1_P + Campaign_Search_Performing_Core_Keywords + Campaign_Self_Employment_E + Campaign_Self_Employment_P + Campaign_Withholding + Campaign_Youtube + Sou
```

Things I know for sure:

1. No item is repeated.
2. No symbols other than alphanumerics and underscore (`_`).
3. No item starts with a number.

I'm not well versed enough in R to understand reading the documentation for `as.formula` or the function call itself.

Any ideas?

Comment: It's just a syntax error, and with a formula that long (too long) you'll just have to look closer and that will be tedious. But there's no way _we'll_ spot the syntax error without the full `as.formula` call and the full character vector you're turning into a formula.

Comment: Ugh, that's what I thought. Do you think just trying to run glm after copy-pasting it would work anyway? Because I've tried parsing the text, but there's no indication of what's wrong. The vector is so long, that when I put it in source, the second half isn't even green.

Comment: Copy and paste it into a plain old text editor and then just start searching.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `<text>:2:10080` is giving you the location of the error.  2nd line, 10080th character.  Consider:

```
parse(text="1 + 1 + 2\n a - 3 b")
# Error in parse(text = "1 + 1 + 2\n a - 3 b") : 
#   <text>:2:8: unexpected symbol
```

Here, the error is with `b`, which is an illegal use of a symbol, and you'll note it is the 8th character of the second line.

Most likely you're missing a `+`, though no way of knowing without the data behind your error.  Also, not to judge or anything, but that's a helluva lot variables to be sticking into a model.  I hope you have lots of data points.

Comment: I  don't have much experience working with substrings, but is there a function to specify what the characters are in that area of the formula? I'm guessing the first line of the call is `"Dependent_Variable ~"`, and the second line is the rest of the formula. The other main problem is there are only 16,000 characters in the text to begin with, so I have no idea how to find the symbol.

Comment: I think that's going to be the best way to go about it. The 100080 error is why I came here first. I was wondering if there was some other solution. The interesting part is that this isn't even the longest vector I've done this with.

Comment: Found it! I forgot to remove spaces in one of the sections.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what worked for me as a work around for this problem.

```
features = make.names(features)

right_side = paste0(features, collapse=" + ")

fml = as.formula(sprintf(" ~ %s", right_side))
```

Comment: ```make.names()``` worked like a charm